# The another answer for a question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, harmonic-oscillator, spring

[image]

[image]

The standard answer for this question is $\frac{2mgh}{(h-L)^2}$ and this is derived from conservation of energy. However, is there another answer to this problem? Since Kate just touches the surface of the water, then it can be like

[image]

Then in this graph, $\frac{2mg}{k}+L=h \implies k=\frac{2mg}{h-L}$

Is this also the right answer? If this is wrong, then why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second answer you found is wrong.  This is because the amplitude is not $mg/k$.

When the mass falls a distance $L$, it has some speed $v=\sqrt{2gL}$. However, when it has fallen a distance of $h$, its speed is zero.  You are assuming the oscillation occurs between these two points when in fact it does not.

In other words, the amplitude of oscillations overlaps with your $L$.